# Can someone help me with a basic LED set up?

Tags: power-supply, led, circuit-analysis

I'm going to make a simple cluster of identical LED's, tight together in a circle. I want to use between 15 and 25 LEDs.  The LEDs are near IR (830 nm) with 1.45 V drop at 100 mA.

What is the optimal approach? Should I wire all in parallel, series, or a mix?

I would like to power from the wall, so I want at least 2.5 A if using 25 x 100 mA LEDs right? And what would be the best voltage?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a critical setup. Use a mixed series/parallel setup, a 9V x 500 mA power supply feeding 4 or 5 series of 5 leds each:  5 * 1.45v =  7,25v   (note that there is a 1,75 difference to 9V), and add a 18 ohm resistor    (1,75V ~= 18 OHM * 100 mA).  Please note that 6 leds in a row would not be a good option, because the internal resistance of the supply could drive its voltage to under 9v and the leds would dim. Using series of 5 leds, a 9v / 500 mA power supply would do the job.

Comment: http://ledcalculator.net/ might help!

Comment: `It doesn't seem to be a critical setup. Use a mixed series/parallel setup, a 9V x 500 mA power supply feeding 4 or 5 series of 5 leds each: 5 * 1.45v = 7,25v (note that there is a 1,75 difference to 9V), and add a 18 ohm resistor (1,75V ~= 18 OHM * 100 mA). Please note that 6 leds in a row would not be a good option, because the internal resistance of the supply could drive its voltage to under 9v and the leds would dim. Using series of 5 leds, a 9v / 500 mA power supply would do the job` 


Thank you very much. So 5 lines (in parallel) of 5 LEDs (in series), with a single 18 ohm resistor?

Comment: @C.P.H. Please don't use parallel branches without individual resistors. Some LEDs may have enough forward resistance to self-balance but if in doubt, don't!

Comment: Thanks winny. So put an 18ohm resistor on each branch of 5 LEDs?

Comment: It's generally a mistake to assume your LED's are "identical".  It leads to designs that are not very robust

Comment: Thanks Scott, how would I treat the situation differently?

Answer (score 3):

First, if the LEDs really only have 1.45 V forward drop at 100 mA, then they are near IR, not visible.

Second, the best parallel series arrangement depends on what power supplies you have available.

Let's say, for example, that you get a 24 V power supply.  Let's also say that you have a series of LEDs that average to 2.0 V forward drop at their intended 100 mA current.  Ideally, you could string (24 V)/(2.0 V) = 12 LEDs in series.  However, that leaves no room to regulate the current.  At the very least, you'd want 11 LEDs in a string, and a resistor to drop the remaining 2.0 V at the desired LED current.  By Ohm's law, that would be (2.0 V)/(100 mA) = 20 Ω.  You could use a 20 Ω resistor if you want to live on the edge.  A 22 Ω resistor gives you some margin to compensate for the LED forward voltages not being exactly what you expected.  This can easily happen due to temperature and normal part variations, for example.

Once you figure out how many LEDs per string, you then decide how many strings you need.  In the example above, if you used 11 LEDs/string, then you'd need two strings to meet your 15 to 25 LEDs spec.  I'd probably go for 10 LEDs/string with a larger series resistor to keep the current more predictable.  That would still give you 20 LEDs with two strings.

Each string draws 100 mA, so two strings draw 200 mA.  You would therefore need a 24 V supply that could deliver at least 200 mA.  I'd therefore want to see it rated for 250 mA minimum to have some margin.  That would be a 6 W supply.

### Added

You now say that these are IR LEDs that really do have about 1.45 V drop at 100 mA.  You should be able to replicate the analysis above using different numbers.

Briefly, (24 V)/(1.45 V) = 16.6, so no more than 15 LEDs per 24 V string.  Your maximum number of LEDs is 25.  Using 24 to keep the strings equal means 12/string.  That's 17.4 V, leaving 6.6 V for the current-setting resistor.  (6.6 V)/(100 mA) = 66 Ω, so 68 Ω it is.  Note that the resistor will dissipate 640 mW, so it should be "1 W" or more.

For better efficiency, you could use 15 LEDs/string and run them at 80 mA and get the same total light output.  At this point, it should be obvious how to figure out the resistor value and its power dissipation.

Comment: Olin thank you so much. So I can do 2 strings of 10 LEDs: 10 x 1.45V = 14.5V per string. If I use a 24V 2A power supply, what resistance would be needed per string?

Comment: Would it be 24v -14.5v = 9.5v. 9.5v x 100mA = 95 Ohms needed? So 100 Ohms would be good? And then do I just run the two strings of 10 LEDs in parallel from 24V source? Thank you

Comment: @C.P: Take another look at Ohm's law and my example above.  The resistor would be (9.5 V)/(100 mA).  Each string would go directly across the supply.  Again though, 1.45 V per LED doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mistyped but copied the equation "(2.0 V)/(100 mA) = 20 Ω", so replacing 2.0 with 9.5 would give 95 Ω? And why doesn't 1.45V per LED make sense? Could the data sheet be wrong? Thank you

Comment: @C.P: The forward voltage is a function of wavelength.  As I said, 1.45 V sounds more like near IR than anything visible.  Red LEDs are usually around 1.8 V.

Comment: Correct, it is infrared. 830nm. So what would you suggest as the best power voltage and set up? thank you

Comment: @C.P: It would be good if you added that to the question to avoid the volunteers here wasting their time on this issue.  You said this was for "light therapy", which implies visible light.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the optimal approach? Should I wire all in parallel, series,
>   or a mix?

First things first - you must drive the LEDs with current. Do not attempt to apply a fixed voltage across one or you will stand a chance of destroying it. Look at the data sheet on page 2 - the typical forward voltage to get 100 mA is 1.45 volts and this is only 50 mV less than the voltage that could produce a current of 450 mA.

This is why when driving LEDs you use a resistor to make things easier to control the current. But you can put several LEDs in series and use one current limiting resistor - using the typical forward voltage value of 1.45 volts you could put (say) ten in series and typically the voltage across them would be 14.5 volts but, you still need a current limiting resistor or mechanism.

Don't put LEDs in parallel either - the one that requires slightly less forward volt drop will hog the majority of the current and be very bright whilst the other will be significantly dimmer.

But you can put LEDs in parallel if you use current limiting resistor on each LED. You can also put series strings of LEDs in parallel providing each string has a current limiting resistor.

So, decide what power supply you want to use and work out the most convenient way to wire the LEDs. The likely method is two strings of 10 with a current limiter resistor in each string. The supply voltage required would be about 16 volts with little comfort. I'd be looking at 20 volts.

You should also note what the data sheet implies about the maximum continuous current and the warming of the device. The forward voltage has a temperature coefficient of -1.8 mV/K and so if the devices warmed 50 degC whilst being activated, the typical figure of 1.45 V forward volt drop would lower to 1.36 volts and this would tend to increase the current taken when using a simple resistive current limiter.

In other words, it might be more appropriate to look at an active current regulation circuit so that 100 mA doesn't creep up under long-usage conditions.

Comment: Andy thank you for you comment. So much to consider it seems. Do you think the usage and temperature issues would be apparent from roughly 20 minutes of daily use? I am in Dublin. And how can I figure out which current limiting resistor to put in a string of 10 LEDs? thank you

Comment: Only a test will determine by how much the device warms. If you are designing a product then you have to be safe and reliable. If you take a 20 volt power supply and 10 series LEDs, the voltage that needs to be dropped across the resistor is 5.5 volts and, at a current of 100 mA this is a 55 ohm resistor. But I just used the typical 1.45 volt drop of a single LED x 10. If you used a 24 volt supply the volt drop would be 9.5 volts and the resistor would therefore be 95 ohms and dissipate nearly a watt of heat.

Comment: This is not true:  "the one that requires slightly less forward volt drop will hog all the current and be very bright whilst the other will hardly illuminate at all."  Assuming there is a difference in Vf, The LED with the lowest individual forward voltage will draw the most current, but no where near all.

Comment: @Misunderstood it is an exaggeration and yes it's not perfectly technically true.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use 15 LEDs in series with a 27 ohms resistor in one strip. Two such strips can be made to accommodate 30 LEDs. current will be approximately 84 or 85 mA.. there will be tiny resistance added by the cable too

Resistors shall be atleast 250 mW rated ones.
24 V, 2 A supply is good to go.

Feel free to comment if more details are needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would probably just go with 1 string of 15 in that case. Can I use a 25 ohm resistor, to get a little more mA for the leds? And what happens if I use 17 leds? 17 x 1.45 = 24.65V

Comment: None of the LEDs will be on with 17 LEDs, current will be zero. With the resistor in series.. Not good idea.

Comment: 25 ohms yes if you have..

Comment: If you need more LEDs, second strip is the way to go.. Assuming you only have 24 V supply.. If you had other supply voltage available, a different combination is indeed possible.

Comment: Thanks Umar. So 24V power supply, 15 LEDs in series, with a 25 or 27 ohm resistor. Seems too easy!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be all in series powered with a CC supply.

15 x 1.45v = 21.75 Vf 
25 x 1.45v = 36.25 Vf

A $28 Mean Well Constant Current HLG-40H-36B has a Vf range of 21.6V - 36V up to 1 Amp. A 10K trimmer resistor across the dim wires will give you ≈ 100mA.

If you have an existing DC source you can use then consider a CCR such as an [On-Semi NSI45090JDT4G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NSI45090JD-D.PDF).

If flux consistency is not an issue a DC CV supply just over the Vf with a resistor will work fine.

To pick the resistor use an [online calculator](https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/ledcalc.php)

Example 15 LED where Vf = 21.75 @ 100 ma and 24V supply

[image]

You can use lower voltage supply by breaking the string in to smaller strings but use a CCR or resistor for each string. In general, do not connect LEDs or strings of LEDs in parallel.